# (closed) How to increment a value which is in an object which is in an array which is in another object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

So I'm trying to code a bot in discord.js where you basically have items in an inventory and when I use an item, its durability goes down. I am using MongoDB Atlas to store all the data. The structure of the inventory is:

```
user: {
  id: 'user-id',
  name: 'user-name',
  inventory: [
    {
      name: 'item',
      durability: 5
    ,
    {
      name: 'another-item',
      durability: 20
    }
  ]
}
```

So I just wanted to find a way to basically just decrement the durability in the item without updating any other item in the inventory array but I wasn't able to get a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update only the value you want.

Also you can use `$inc` to increment the value (in this case increment by -1, i.e, decrement)

```
db.collection.update({
  "id": "user-id"
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "inventory.$[element].durability": -1
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.name": "item" //here use the name of the object you want to update
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nMhg5JLN_aA)

Comment: Yeah wait, I got it. The error came because I was using `findOneAndUpdate`, not `updateOne`. Thanks for the answer, it works now!